# Confused About Seemingly Abnormal Use of ⇔ In Context of Reidemeister Moves

Tags: notation, definition, knot-theory

https://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/annual-report/ncolorability.pdf

The above pdf about Reidemeister moves contains this symbol

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

It says "The expression for the crossing of a single twist is $a_{1} + a_{2} \Leftrightarrow 2a_{1}$" where $\Leftrightarrow$ seems to be modular congruency.(pg 3, Reidemeister Case 1)

It also says "There are now four strands $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}$ and two crossings which most must satisfy $a_{1} + a_{3} \Leftrightarrow2a_{2} \equiv 0$." Here , $\Leftrightarrow$ seems to be about subtraction or something.

Could someone please explain what this symbol means? Wikipedia claims it has to do with logical equivalence, though is sometimes used incorrectly for "iff". But neither of these makes sense to me in this context.

Comment: The current title of your question is not very helpful to other users, since you've already identified the symbol as $\Leftrightarrow$ and the title doesn't give any context. 
I'd suggest something more like "The atypical meaning of $\Leftrightarrow$ in the context of a discussion of Reidemeister moves".

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you! Will make the change!

Comment: @MarkS. Do you think the title is good now or is there anything I should change?

Comment: It looks like a font issue with that pdf. Every place I can find where it should be a hyphen or minus sign in math mode is replaced by $\Leftrightarrow$. (This document looks like it's a student report, just so you're aware.)

Comment: @KyleMiller Thank you!